# Laravel Auth::attempt/login page isn't work properly

Tags: laravel-4, authentication, forms-authentication

my registration page works finely .data is inserted properly into table called "registered_users".My login page is not work properly.

routes.php

```
<?php



 Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});


//About page
 Route::get('about', function()
{
    return View::make('about');
});

 //reister route

Route::get('register', function(){

return View::make('register');

});

Route::post('register_action', function()
{
        $obj = new RegisterController() ;
        return $obj->store();
});

Route::get('login', function(){

return View::make('login');

});


Route::post('logincheck', function(){

// username and password validation rule

    $data =  Input::except(array('_token')) ;
    $rule  =  array(
            'name'       => 'required',
            'password'   => 'required',
    ) ;
    $message = array(
       'password.required' => 'The Password field is required.',
       'name.required'      => 'The Username  is required.',
    );


    $v = Validator::make($data,$rule);





    if ($v->fails()) {

            // username or password missing

            // validation fails

            // used to retain input values

            Input::flash ();

            // return to login page with errors

            return Redirect::to('login')

            ->withInput()

            ->withErrors ($v->messages ());

    } else {

                    $userdata = array (

                    'name' => Input::get('name'),

                    'password' => Input::get('password')

                );

                //var_dump($userdata);
                If (Auth::attempt ($userdata)) {

        // authentication success, enters home page

         return Redirect::to('home');

     } else {

         // authentication fail, back to login page with errors

         return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors('Incorrect login details');


         }//end if 




    }//end of v else

});


// Route::get ('home',function(){

//  return View::make('home');

// });
Route::get ('test',function(){

    return View::make('test');

    });

Route::group (array ('before' => 'auth'), function () {

    Route::get ('home',function(){

    return View::make('home');

    });

});
Route::get ('logout',function(){

Auth::logout ();

return Redirect::to('login');

});
```

i checked **Route::post('logincheck', function()** in **routes.php** step by step ...everything is ok...but following part of  **Route::post('logincheck', function()** in **routes.php**  is not work properly .whether i enter correct name and password or wrong in log in form ,it just shows 'Incorrect login details' message

```
If (Auth::attempt ($userdata)) {

        // authentication success, enters home page

         return Redirect::to('home');

     } else {

         // authentication fail, back to login page with errors

         return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors('Incorrect login details');


         }//end if
```

login.blade.php

```
    @extends('layout')

    @section('main')
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Registrationhhjh</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <section class="header">
        <div class="bannner">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Sign In</h1>

            @if ($errors->any())

            <ul style="color:red;">

            {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li>:message</li>')) }}

            </ul>

            @endif

  {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'logincheck')) }}
             {{ Form::text('name', '', array('placeholder'=>'Name')) }}<br><br>
            {{ Form::password('password', '', array('placeholder'=>'Password')) }}<br><br>
            {{ Form::submit('Sign in', array('class'=>'btn btn-success')) }}
            <!-- {{ Form::submit('register', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) }} -->
            {{ HTML::link('register', 'Register', array('class' => 'btn btn-info'))}}

            {{ Form::close() }}



           </div>

        </section>





    </body>
    </html>

    @stop
```

User.php(model).i think may be there is problems in User.php(model)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'registered_users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
    //protected $hidden = array('password');

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
  {
    return $this->getKey();
  }
  public function getAuthPassword()
  {
    return $this->password;
  } 
  public function getRememberToken()
  {
    return $this->remember_token;
  }
  public function setRememberToken($value)
  {
    $this->remember_token = $value;
  }
    public function getRememberTokenName()
  {
    return "remember_token";
  }
  public function getReminderEmail()
  {
    return $this->email;
  }

}
```

auth.php..can anyone tell me what is **'table' => 'users',** in **auto.php**?....once i rename it as 'table' => 'registered_users' because i have no 'users' named table.but the problem remain (same i can not go to 'home page' )

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Authentication Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the authentication driver that will be utilized.
    | This driver manages the retrieval and authentication of the users
    | attempting to get access to protected areas of your application.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'eloquent',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
    | Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
    | is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
    |
    */

    'model' => 'User',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
    | table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
    | default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'users',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reminder Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the settings for password reminders, including a view
    | that should be used as your password reminder e-mail. You will also
    | be able to set the name of the table that holds the reset tokens.
    |
    | The "expire" time is the number of minutes that the reminder should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'reminder' => array(

        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

        'table' => 'password_reminders',

        'expire' => 60,

    ),

);
```

i use wamp server..i use laravel 4.2..my database name is **mydb**...table name 
**registered_users** 
table has *id*,*name*,*email*,*password*,*remember_token*,*created_at*,*updated_at* fields

*remember_token* field type is varchar(270)...is there is any limitation in *remember_token* size

please help me anyone what is the problem in login system?

Here is my RegisterController.php

```
<?php

class RegisterController extends BaseController {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish to use controllers instead of, or in addition to, Closure
    | based routes. That's great! Here is an example controller method to
    | get you started. To route to this controller, just add the route:
    |
    |   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
    |
    */


    // public function store()
    // {
 //        Register::saveFormData(Input::except(array('_token')));
 //    }

    public function store()
    {
            $data =  Input::except(array('_token')) ;
            $rule  =  array(
                    'name'       => 'required|unique:registered_users',
                    'email'      => 'required|email|unique:registered_users',
                    'password'   => 'required|min:6|same:cpassword',
                    'cpassword'  => 'required|min:6'
                ) ;
            $message = array(
                   'cpassword.required' => 'The confirm password field is required.',
                   'cpassword.min'      => 'The confirm password must be at least 6 characters',
                   'password.same'      => 'The :attribute and confirm password field must match.',
               );
            $validator = Validator::make($data,$rule,$message);

           // $validator = Validator::make($data,$rule);

            if ($validator->fails())
            {
                    return Redirect::to('register')
                            ->withErrors($validator->messages());
            }
            else
            {
                    Register::saveFormData(Input::except(array('_token','cpassword')));

                    return Redirect::to('register')
                            ->withMessage('Successfully registered');
            }
    }

}
```

Here is model/Register.php

```
<?php

class Register extends Eloquent {
        protected $guarded = array();
        protected $table = 'registered_users'; // database table name
        public $timestamps = 'false' ; // to disable default timestamp fields

        // model function to store form data to database
        public static function saveFormData($data)
        {
            DB::table('registered_users')->insert($data);
        }

}
```

Finally i solved my problem.My problem is that i stored my password as plaintext.for solving my problem i just edited my models\Register.php file .
Here is my edited models\Register.php

```
<?php

class Register extends Eloquent {
        protected $guarded = array();
        protected $table = 'registered_users'; // database table name
        public $timestamps = 'false' ; // to disable default timestamp fields

        // model function to store form data to database
        public static function saveFormData($data)
        {
          //  DB::table('registered_users')->insert($data);
                $name = Input::get('name');
                $email = Input::get('email');
                $password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));


                $user = new User;

                $user->name = $name;
                $user->email = $email;
                $user->password = $password;

                $user->save();
        }

}
```

Comment: Are your passwords hashed when you register the user? I dont see it anywhere...

Comment: Show us your RegisterController, I've a feeling that you're storing the passwords in plaintext.

Comment: i now add my RegisterController.php and model/Register.php file in question.yes my password is stored in table as plaintext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Auth::attempt() function automatically hashes your password. The problem is that you are storing your passwords as plain text. So when the method checks if your password is correct, it hashes it and compares it to the saved password. That password is not hashed, so it wont work unless you hash your password upon registry.

Comment: yeah Maarten00 this is the main problem ..i already solved it .thanks for your reply .i just changed the code in model/Register.php .above i add my edited Register.php